# Is pure Ajax a library of javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Please I know this question sounds amateur. I am not talking of jquery or any other javascript library which include ajax properties. Is pure AJAX  a library of javascript?

**I am asking because I am not sure how switching off javascript could affect my ajax request to external pages.**

### **Please if yes, is there any way I can do asynchronous transfer even when the javascript is turned off?**

Comment: The `XMLHttpRequest` API can only be exploited with JavaScript code in a web browser, so yes. If JavaScript is disabled, then your page cannot do ajax stuff.

Comment: @Pointy Please how do you handle it when creating pages? Do you also create PHP code in the same page too in case javascript is not on? or you just don't consider those who turn their javascript off?

Comment: PHP code in the page won't help, because PHP is server-side technology.  The best you can do is provide text to explain why the page doesn't work.

Comment: Your follow-on question about non-`XMLHttpRequest` ways to do asynchronous transfer could be answered in a number of ways. Can you please provide more details, possibly in a separate question post?

Answer (score 2):

'Pure AJAX' - i.e. `XMLHttpRequest` - was [added to Internet Explorer 5 first, and is now supported in all modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). So while technically not a part of "core JavaScript" (e.g. some version of ECMAScript), it is a JavaScript API that has been available in all popular browsers for many years.

JavaScript must be enabled in your browser for such calls to work, as AJAX calls are JavaScript calls.